# Reading data faster from postgreSQL table with query with psycopg2 copy_expert

Tags: python, postgresql, performance, psycopg2

I am using *copy_expert* from psycopg2 to read (a lot of) data from a table using a *specific* query as I don't need the whole table. It works fine like this:

```
s_buf = io.StringIO()
conn = self.conn

cur = conn.cursor()
query = f"""
    copy 
    (select {",".join(columns)} from {self.table}
    where symbol in {tuple(data)})
    to STDOUT WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER '\t')
    """
cur.copy_expert(query, s_buf, size=8192)
s_buf.seek(0)
return list(csv.DictReader(s_buf, delimiter="\t", fieldnames=columns))
```

Here, *data* is a list with 150 values. The resulting output has 800.000 rows which is not much. However, the *copy_expert* query takes almost 50 seconds which is way too slow. I know it is possible in general to read data from SQL a lot faster than that and doing the query in dBeaver is much faster as well. How can I make this reading of data faster? Can I take advantage of threading/pooling the query somehow? Should I add indices to the table to make querying it faster?

Any help or comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. In my case, the *symbol* column represented reasonably large groups of the data in the table and creating a simple b-tree index on it made the query run in 2 seconds compared to 50 seconds:

```
CREATE INDEX symbol_idx ON mytable USING btree ("symbol")
```